# Python 3 regular expression for $ but not $$ in a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need to match one of the following anywhere in a string:

```
${aa:bb[99]}
${aa:bb}
${aa}
```

but not:

```
$${aa:bb[99]}
$${aa:bb}
$${aa}
```

my python 3 regex is:

```
pattern = **r"[^\$|/^]**\$\{(?P<section>[a-zA-Z]+?\:)?(?P<key>[a-zA-Z]+?)(?P<value>\[[0-9]+\])?\}"
```

What I'm looking for, is the proper way to say not $ or beginning of a string. The block `r"[^\$|/^]"` will properly detect all cases but will fail if my string starts at the first character.

I trie, without success:

```
r"[^\$|\b]... 
r"[^\$|\B]...
r"[^\$]...
r"[^\$|^]
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why not explicitly say you expect one dollar sign, as in `\${1}`?

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin: because that does not work.

Comment: `(?<!\$)\$\{(?P<section>[a-z]+)(?::(?P<key>[a-z]+))?(?P<value>\[\d+\])?\}`

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin you do realize that `\${1}` is **exactly the same** as `\$` right?

Answer (score 8):

Use a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\$)
```

and then follow it by the thing you actually want to match. This will ensure that the thing you actually want to match is not preceded by a `$` (i.e. not preceded by a match for `\$`):

```
(?<!\$)\$\{(?P<section>[a-zA-Z]+?\:)?(?P<key>[a-zA-Z]+?)(?P<value>\[[0-9]+\])?\}
     ^  ^
     |  |
     |  +--- The dollar sign you actually want to match
     |
     +--- The possible second preceding dollar sign you want to exclude
```

> `(?<!...)`
>
> Matches if the current position in the string is not preceded
>   by a match for `...`. This is called a negative lookbehind assertion.
>   Similar to positive lookbehind assertions, the contained pattern must
>   only match strings of some fixed length and shouldn’t contain group
>   references. Patterns which start with negative lookbehind assertions
>   may match at the beginning of the string being searched.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: I actually like this answer better than mine because it explains what the negative lookbehind does clearly. For a new user, this can be at least as important as having a working example. +1

Answer (score 3):

You can use a negative lookbehind `(?<!\$)` to say "not preceded by `$`":

```
(?<!\$)\${[^}]*}
```

I have simplified the part between the brackets a bit to focus on the "one and only one `$` part".

Here is a [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/ohMGEC/1).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Amber for the ideas. I followed the same train of thought you suggest using negative look ahead. I tried them all with  https://regex101.com/r/G2n0cO/1/. The only one that succeed almost perfectly is:

```
(?:^|[^\$])\${(?:(?P<section>[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+?)\:)??(?P<key>[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+?)(?:\[(?P<index>[0-9]+?)\])??\}
```

I still had to add a check to remove the last non-dollar character. at the end of the sample below. For history I kept a few of the iterations I made since I posted this question:

```
    # keep tokens ${[section:][key][\[index\]]}and skip false ones 
    # pattern = r"\$\{((?P<section>.+?)\:)?(?P<key>.+?)(\[(?P<index>\d+?)\])+?\}" 
    # pattern = r'\$\{((?P<section>\S+?)\:)??(?P<key>\S+?)(\[(?P<index>\d+?)\])?\}'
    # pattern = r'\$\{((?P<section>[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+?)\:)??(?P<key>[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+?)(\[(?P<index>[0-9]+?)\])??\}'
    pattern = r'(?:^|[^\$])\${(?:(?P<section>[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+?)\:)??(?P<key>[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+?)(?:\[(?P<index>[0-9]+?)\])??\}'

    analyser = re.compile(pattern)
    mo = analyser.search(value, 0)
    log.debug(f'got match object: {mo}')
    while not mo is None:
        log.debug(f'in while loop, level={level}')

        if level > MAX_LEVEL:
            raise RecursionError(f"to many recursive call to _substiture_text() while processing '{value}'.")
        else:
            level +=1

        start = mo.start()
        end   = mo.end()
        # re also captured the first non $ sign symbol
        if value[start] != '$': 
            start += 1
```